# Unable to completely shrink wrap and center an element

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code to create a shrink wrapped and centered page. Everything is fine  if the browser window is wider than the maximum potential width. In this case, there are three floated paragraphs with fixed widths. If the window is wide enough so that they can all float on the same line, the div is centered and wrapped correctly. But when the browser is narrower, and one of the paragraphs wraps to the next line, the div expands to the full width of the window and is no longer shrink wrapped. I have tried everything I can think of and am going to give up and move on unless someone has a new idea. Oddly, it works well in ie7. Go figure.

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">

header, footer, nav, section, article { display: block; }

body
{
    font-size:1em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color:#000;
    background:#ddd url(images/BG.jpg);
}

/*********** Start shrink wrapped and centered layout styles ************************/
#page {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#container {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    left:50%;
}
#content 
{

    float:left;
    position:relative;
    right:50%;
}
/*********** End shrink wrapped and centered layout styles ************************/
#content
{
    border:solid 4px #bbb;
}
p
{
    width:20em;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="page">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
        <p>p1</p>
        <p>p2</p>
        <p>p3</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could try using `diplay: inline-block` instead of `float` - however this would not work in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/j6NuE/

Comment: When I use inline-block, I get the same behavior. The problem I am having is when the browser width forces the floating paragraphs to wrap. The containing div isn't shrunk any more. I want it to continue to shrink down as the paragraphs wrap. In this case it would shrink when the first one wrapped, and then shrink again when the next one wrapped. So there would be three possible widths for the containing div (60em, 40em or 20em), depending on the width of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with media queries. It will degrade gracefully in outdated browsers.

```
p {width:200px; height:20px; background:salmon; float:left; margin:10px; padding:10px;}
div {background:lightblue; overflow:auto; width:720px; margin:0 auto;}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
 div{width:480px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 div{width:240px;}
}
```

[Demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/1630203)

Answer (score 0):

To make  display:inline-block and centering work you need to set text-align:center on the parent container